# How can I fill in a table from a file when using flyway migration scripts

Tags: postgresql, flyway, java-16

I have scripts

```sql
/*The extension is used to generate UUID*/
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

-- auto-generated definition
create table users
(
    id  uuid not null DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        constraint profile_pkey
            primary key,
    em    varchar(255),
    user varchar(255)
);
```

In IDE Intellij Idea (a project with Spring Boot):

- src/main/resources/db-migration
- src/main/resources/sql_scripts :
  copy.sql
  user.txt

I'm just trying to run a simple Sql command for now to see that everything works clearly

- copy.sql

```sql
COPY profile FROM '/sql_scripts/user.txt'
    USING DELIMITERS ',' WITH NULL AS '\null';
```

- user.txt

```
'm@mai.com', 'sara'
's@yandex.ru', 'jacobs'
```

But when I run the copy command, I get an error

> ERROR: could not open file...

Maybe who knows how it should work and what needs to be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

Strong possibility its a pathing issue; could you try, instead of

`COPY profile FROM '/sql_scripts/user.txt'`

doing

`COPY profile FROM './sql_scripts/user.txt'`

(or an absolute path)

Comment: I have error : ERROR: could not open file "./sql_scripts/user.txt" for reading: No such file or ....

Comment: ...When preparing to copy a file from the underlying operating system, remember that the file specified must be readable by the postmaster process (i.e., the user which PostgreSQL is running as), since the backend reads the file directly. Additionally, the filename must be provided with an absolute path; an attempt to use a relative path will result in an error...